# Uninitialized constant QuickbooksWebConnector

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I want to use QBO in my Rails 3 app, so I have used a QuickbooksWebConnector gem and written:

```
mount QuickbooksWebConnector::Engine => "/quickbooks_web_connector"
```

in routes.rb. I ran `bundle install` and started the server, but this give me the following error:

> uninitialized constant QuickbooksWebConnector

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I got it!

**Install the Gem :**

`gem install qbwc`

**Add it to your Gemfile :**

`use gem 'qbwc'`

**Run the generator :**

`bundle install`

**Run the generator**

`rails generate qbwc:install`

Follow this link :
https://github.com/skryl/qbwc